# Error CS0411 al unir dos tablas con Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join, lambda

Estoy intentando unir dos tablas mediante EntityFramework con expresiones Lambda, el problema es cuando genero el join, ya que me muestra el error CS0411:

> Los argumentos de tipo para el método 'Queryable.Join(IQueryable, IEnumerable, Expression>, Expression>, Expression>)' no se pueden inferir a partir del uso. Pruebe a especificar los argumentos de tipo explícitamente

El codigo que estoy utilizando es el siguiente:

```
var test = context.ComAcPartidas
    .Where(x => x.NuRecepcion == NuRecepcion)
    .Join(context.Cn_CatArticulos, //En esta line me marca el error en el Join
    A => A.NuAceite,
    B => B.IdArticulo,
    (A, B) => new { A, B });
```

Alguna idea de por qué me ocurre esto?

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Creo que NuAceite y B.IdArticulo no son iguales esos campos son con los que haces Macth en tu JOIN?

Comment: Tienes toda la razón NuAceite es de tipo byte y IdArticulo es de tipo int, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada amigo Saludos estamos para ayudar :D

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo mas simple recomendaria la notacion linq en lugar de los metodos de extension

```
var test = from partida in context.ComAcPartidas
            join articulo in context.Cn_CatArticulos on partida.NuAceite equals articulo.IdArticulo
            where partida.NuRecepcion == NuRecepcion
            select new {
                    Partida = partida, 
                    Articulo = articulo
               };
```

como veras es mas simple de entender con esta notacion

[join (Cláusula, Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause)